# New foundation in homotopy type theory

Tags: lo.logic, type-theory, homotopy-type-theory, new-foundations

Is there any model of NF (New Foundations) on HoTT (homotopy type theory)?

Because there is a model of ZF(C) on HoTT ([The HoTT book](https://homotopytypetheory.org/book/), Section 10.5) and NF on ZFC (by [this Wikipedia articile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Foundations#Models_of_NFU)), I think anyway we have a model of NF in that way. I am looking for easier ways to define one.

I tried to define a model by assigning $\mathsf{Set}_{\mathcal{U}_n}$ to the collection of sets of type $n$, but I got stuck when I tried to define the membership relation between $x: \mathsf{Set}_{\mathcal{U}_{n}}$ and $y: \mathsf{Set}_{\mathcal{U}_{n+1}}$.

Comment: The consistency of NF from ZFC is still open. What you linked is the fact that NFU is consistent relative to ZFC.

Comment: Open is too strong a word. It's more like "not yet definitively verified".

Comment: @Emil: Sure. I met Randall at some point and he gave me a full account of the proof he had at the time. It's been three months or so, which is forever in new developments as far as his manuscript goes.

Comment: Types do not have a global membership relation. Since in NF you need such a relation, it is best to think of a model of NF as something that builds *both* the universe of sets and the membership relation simultaneously. I would try to define the type $\mathsf{NF}$ of NF-sets and the membership relation $\in_\mathsf{NF}$ simultaneously as an inductive-inductive definition.

Comment: It would certainly be interesting if there were such a model, though it's very far from clear how you'd do it. I'm not sure Holmes' proof would translate well into a typed context, but Holmes has expressed suspicion that any inductive construction of $\in_{NF}$ would be at least as ugly as his proof...

Answer (score 1):

It is not difficult to build models of **Constructive NF** on type theory, but if you want to get models of standard **NF** I don't think you can avoid the various sufferings that have been endured by previous generations.[1][2]

Equality and membership can be obtained from **Coq**'s **IZF** implementation, and the only unimplemented part is *stratified formula checker*, which is also not difficult. However in general you can only go so far, you do not simply get **NF** consistency from **CNF**. (for example it is not clear if **CNF** implies axiom of infinity)

If [2] is correct, then we don't need a stronger type theory than **Calculus of Constructions (CC)**, let alone **HoTT**.

If works in **intensional NF** (= just membership + stratified formula checker) and considers the *setoid*, *groupoid* structure on **intensional NF**, then the **HoTT** is useful for the extra design over **CC**. **intensional NF** is purer constructivism than the **NF(U)**, but it will also be more different from the standard **NF(U)**.

---

[1] https://arxiv.org/abs/1503.01406

[2] https://arxiv.org/abs/1406.4060

Comment: I would be a bit wary of [2], the Gabbay preprint.  Earlier versions of the paper had significant gaps/errors in them (though certainly also promising ideas); I haven’t read the latest versions carefully, but as far as I know they’ve not generally been accepted by other experts in the field.